# Django admin import export - 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: django, csv, import, admin

In Django admin page i am trying to import the student table using the import_export library but it gives an

> TypeError at /admin/catalog/student/import/ 'NoneType' object is not
> callable Request Method: POST Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/student/import/ Django Version:
> 2.2.2 Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value:    'NoneType' object is not callable Exception Location:
> C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py
> in write_to_tmp_storage, line 229 Python Executable:
> C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.7.3 Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\django_projects\django_projects\glacier',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\Scripts\python37.zip',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\Scripts',
> 'c:\users\sdixit23.ead\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib',
> 'c:\users\sdixit23.ead\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf',
> 'C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\odf']
> Server time:    Wed, 28 Aug 2019 17:31:27 +0100

I have tried checking the models.py and admin.py files. I even tried recreating the site again but i have no clue why its not working.
In fact its not working for any of my models.

## admin.py

```
class StudentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('student_ID',
                    'student_First_Name',
                    'student_Last_Name',
                    'student_DOB',
                    'gender',
                    'student_Gmail',
                    'parent_Name',
                    'parent_Email',
                    'contact_Number',
                    'city',
                    'country',
                    'comments',
                    )

# Register the admin class with the associated model
admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

## models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    """Model representing a Student."""

    student_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10, help_text='Enter Student ID as PYNNN')
    student_First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Student First Name')
    student_Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Student First Name')
    student_DOB = models.DateField(help_text='Enter Date of Birth as YYYY-MM-DD', null=True)

    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=STUDENT_GENDER,
        blank=True,
        default='',
        help_text='Enter Student Gender',
    )

    student_Gmail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter student Gmail-id. Its Mandatory to use Gmail-id', null=True)
    parent_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Parent Full Name', null=True)
    parent_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Parent Email', null=True)
    contact_Number = models.CharField(max_length=11, help_text='Enter Mobile Number (e.g. 07910100045)', null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter City Name', null=True)
    country = CountryField(null=True, default= "United Kingdom")
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=200, help_text='Any Specific comments', null=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular student instance."""
        return reverse('student-detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
    
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.student_First_Name} {self.student_Last_Name}'
```

The expected result was the "preview page" instead i see this error

```
TypeError at /admin/catalog/student/import/
'NoneType' object is not callable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/student/import/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception Location: C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py in write_to_tmp_storage, line 229
Python Executable:  C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    ['C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\django_projects\\django_projects\\glacier',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\sdixit23.ead\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\sdixit23.ead\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\sdixit23.EAD\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages\\odf']
Server time:    Wed, 28 Aug 2019 17:31:27 +0100
```

Comment: did you defined resource_class in admin.py?

Comment: No i haven't defined the class. I just did what was mentioned in this Youtube video [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYIuvSwLsMc

Comment: What's your setting for `IMPORT_EXPORT_TMP_STORAGE_CLASS`?

Comment: @giveJob you don't need to specify a `resource_class` if you just want to use the default `modelresourcefactory` provided by import-export.

Comment: @Ranchoddasshyamaldaschanchad the error occurs when calling `get_tmp_storage_class()()` meaning `get_tmp_storage_class()` returned `None`. That can only happen if you wrongly set `IMPORT_EXPORT_TMP_STORAGE_CLASS`

Comment: The values are `#import-export feature related
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True
IMPORT_EXPORT_SKIP_ADMIN_LOG = False
IMPORT_EXPORT_TMP_STORAGE_CLASS = None
IMPORT_EXPORT_IMPORT_PERMISSION_CODE = None
IMPORT_EXPORT_EXPORT_PERMISSION_CODE = None`

Comment: Thanks for your help friends. I have crossed over that problem but a new problem has corpped up.

Now i am getting  these errors

Errors
Line number: 1 - 'id'
, PY003, Rishika, Jain, 01/01/2006, F, rishaaika.jain@gmail.com, Hitesh Jain, hitesaah.jaaain@gmail.com, 7705340091, Mansotay, GB, NA
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sdixit23.EAD\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 492, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)

KeyError: 'id'

Comment: I have now solved the problem using the ResourceClass to override the primary key.